# NIVO SLIDER - Make a slide a link?

Tags: slider

Is it possible to make a slide a link in NIVO SLIDER?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just wrap the image in an anchor tag `<a>`

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="media/images/headers/phono1.jpg" alt="No Link" />
    <a href="http://www.pinelakedesign.com"><img src="media/images/headers/photo2.jpg" title="Linked Up" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvote was for. That is exactly the code I'm using and the links work

Comment: The above solution doesn't work for me either. They appeared linked in the source but not when displaying.

Comment: @Bry4n can I see what you have going?  I have had similar problems in the past when my block level elements are wrestling with `z-index` priority.

Comment: I eventually got this working by using a piece of the nivo slider CSS. So the above works as long as you have the CSS in place.

Comment: you don't need the whole css file - you can just set the links to a width and height of 100% and position absolute and a z-index above 10

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem with links in IE all versions, other browsers were working OK, solved with adding:

```
background-color:#fff; 
filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
/other than IE/ 
-moz-opacity:0;
-khtml-opacity: 0;
opacity: 0;
```

to the `**.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink**` of the `nivo-slider.css`

Answer (score 3):

I just added `z-index: 101` to `.nivo-imageLink`. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding anchor tags worked for all browsers/versions except IE.
The solution by Nejc Menard above worked perfectly for me.

Others did not.

We are currently running: jQuery Nivo Slider v3.1 with jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Sorry Nejc:  Was not able to comment on Nejc's answer.. as I'm a new badger to this site.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in my .css file fixed the problem:

```
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink{opacity:0 !important;}
```