# Making an Image a Hyperlink in Nivo Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nivo-slider

I am working with NivoSlider and have been unable to make the Image a link. I know, i can use captions to create a link. But, that isn't enought. For better accessibility, i want the image to be a link too.

There is one similar question on StackOverflow, but it is for a very old version of Nivo.

I am using this syntax for the slider.

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default container">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <div class='slide'><a href='#'><img src='abc.png'></a>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'><a href='http://google.com'><img src='google.png' title=''></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works perfectly. The slideshow, transition, captions, etc. But, I am unable to make the anchor link work on the entire image. :(

If anyone knows how to make it work, then please let me know.

EDIT: Here is the only piece of CSS written by me:

```
.slider-wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: fade(white,80%);
    padding-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.slide-title {
    .font;
    color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: This is probably CSS related... Your images are probably in an absolute position (instead of the anchor) so the anchor's height/width is at 0. In the debug panel of your browser, make sure the anchor takes up the whole width/height of the image. Or post your CSS code in the question.

Comment: _on the entire page_. What do you mean with that?

Comment: @vyx.ca I have added the css. Could you provide me some css to help me out.

Comment: @RohitSmith your css isn't relevant. .slide-title isn't even used and you didn't provide the css to the .slide, .slide a

Answer (score 0):

I am very late to party. it may be useful for someone

HTML

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
              <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <a href="http://www.google.ae/" target="_new"><img  title="#htmlcaption1"  src="images/01.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="http://www.yahoo.ae/" target="_new"><img title="#htmlcaption2"  src="images/02.png" alt=""></a>                 
              </div>
          </div>
```

CSS

```
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
background:white; 
filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
opacity: 0;
z-index: 8;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

I removed the attribute
image title="#caption"

That was it.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the wrapper divs with class "slide" it will work just fine.
For example this is from nivo slider's demo

```
<a href="#1"><img src="images/toystory.jpg" data-thumb="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <a href="#2"><img src="images/up.jpg" data-thumb="images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" /></a>
                <a href="#3"><img src="images/walle.jpg" data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" /></a>
                <a href="#4"><img src="images/nemo.jpg" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" /></a>
```

or checkout this thread,

[NIVO SLIDER - Make a slide a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934454/nivo-slider-make-a-slide-a-link)